# How to make photoshop pencil tool 8x8 pixel square

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-art

I was making some pixel art and at some point I doubled the image size so now in order to continue to make my nice squares I want the pixel tool to be an 8x8 pixel square tip. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the Brush Palette click on the arrow to load Square Brushes. See image below, might look a bit different if you're on CS6, I'm not too sure:

[image]

Comment: This does look different on CS6. I wonder if anyone could explain how to do it there...

Comment: @zakgottlieb come into the chat and someone will probably be able to help you out. Or if you come into the chat and show me screenshots I might be able to tell you myself.

Comment: on CS6 CC I see no square shape options.

Comment: @BenRacicot did you load them? Click where it says "Load Brushes"

Comment: On CC versions, you can get to the square brush presets by clicking the little cog in the top right of the brush selector dropdown (or right click on the canvas with the brush selected) https://i.imgur.com/lV096rB.png

Answer (score 0):

I want to say the pencil tool is always square, but I'm not 100%. The easy way I use to change the size of the brush is using the [ and ] keys. This will increase and decrease the brush radius.
Right clicking while using a brush tool will give you size and edge hardness.

Comment: The "round" pencil brush is square up to 3px, but above that it is no longer a square.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has square brush presets of various sizes. In Photoshop CC you need to  [load legacy brushes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/145468/2413) to get access to the Square Brushes group.

[image: Brushes palette in Photoshop with Square Brushes preset open, with "Hard Square 8 pixels" brush selected]